# Gauge and mass eigenstates

Tags: feynman-diagrams

We learn in the Standard Model that the gauge fields can be either in mass or gauge eigenstates. I wonder in the calculations with Feynmann diagram, which states should I use.

Comment: Mass eigenstates may be more convenient as their propagators are diagonal.

Comment: How about the vertices then? Which coupling should I use?

Comment: For the standard model, they are all in the text books.

Comment: Can you give me a reference book?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Bailin & Love have the Feynman rules of the electroweak theory in. For the rest you do not have to worry.